# function () does not exit in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

I am using the resource route. And now, I would like to add another route:

```
Route::resource('discussion', 'DiscussionsController');
Route::post('/discussion/reply/{id}',[
    'use' => 'DiscussionsController@reply',
    'as' => 'discussion.reply'
]);`
```

And here is reply function,

```
public function reply($id)
{
    $discussion = Discussion::find($id);

    $reply = Reply::create([
        'user_id'=>Auth::id(),
        'discussion_id' => $id,
        'content'=> \request()->reply
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This is the blade that redirects to the store function.

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="card-body">
        Leave a reply

        <form method="post" action="{{route('discussion.reply', ['id'=> $discussion->id])}}">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="reply" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Reply</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the exact error you get? Can you include stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but from a glance I would say that it's because you have `use` instead of `uses` for your `Route`.

Try changing

```
'use' => 'DiscussionsController@reply',
```

to

```
'uses' => 'DiscussionsController@reply',
```

---

Second of all, you don't need the `\` with `\request()->reply`.

Change it to `request()->reply` or even `request('reply')`

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? If you're going to downvote an answer you should at least explain why you have done so.

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the order of the routes

Instead of

```
Route::resource('discussion', 'DiscussionsController');
Route::post('/discussion/reply/{id}',[
    'use' => 'DiscussionsController@reply',
    'as' => 'discussion.reply'
]);
```

Use that

```
Route::post('/discussion/reply/{id}',[
    'use' => 'DiscussionsController@reply',
    'as' => 'discussion.reply'
]);
Route::resource('discussion', 'DiscussionsController');
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but the reason that route order doesn't matter in this case is because you have a 3rd uri segment so Laravel will know that you're not trying to reach one of the resource routes which only has 2 uri segments at most.

Comment: still not working. 
There is closure in route action